# SAP Spartacus form personalization

Tags: java, angular, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I need to modify a register form to show an error message, if there are already an account registered with a given email. SAP Hybris backend, Spartacus storefront in Angular. Currently, I have a custom validator class, which works correctly:

```
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
    public class EmailExistingValidator implements Validator {
    /*
    ...
    */
        @Override
        public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
            Object fieldValue = errors.getFieldValue(this.fieldPath);
    
            if (fieldValue == null || fieldValue instanceof String &&userIdExists((String) fieldValue)) {
                errors.rejectValue(this.fieldPath, "field.required", new String[]{this.fieldPath}, "This email is already in use.");
            }
        }
    }
```

If the case, the storefront shows a red error message : "UID is not valid", but I want to change that to "Email address is not valid or it is already in use".

How can I do that?

As I investigated the issue, this string in the storefront comes from a const named validationError.invalid.uid located in a file named spartacus-assets.js, like this:

```
invalid: {
                card_expirationMonth: 'The credit card expiration date entered is not valid.',
                firstName: 'First Name entered is not valid.',
                lastName: 'Last Name entered is not valid.',
                password: 'Password entered is not valid.',
                uid: 'UID is not valid.',
            },
```

As far as I know, the confirmation and/or error messages are populated somehow like this (line 6):

```
handleValidationError(_request, response) {
    this.getErrors(response)
        .filter((e) => e.type === 'ValidationError')
        .forEach((error) => {
        this.globalMessageService.add({
            key: `httpHandlers.validationErrors.${error.reason}.${error.subject}`,
        }, GlobalMessageType.MSG_TYPE_ERROR);
    });
```

These are out of the box, all located in node_modules, so I cant rewrite things here, because after an *npm install* they all will be gone.

It is possible to change that message? Is there any solution to solve this problem? I missed something or I am wrong? I welcome any comments, I am very new to SAP Commerce, as you can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the http error handling logic is centralized in the [HttpErrorHandler](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/http-error-handling/)s classes.

The http validation errors are handled in a generic way - the error type and message from backend is converted to frontend [translation key](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/), then translated for the current langauge and displayed in the global message component in the frontend UI.

If you want to handle differently some specific error from some specific endpoint (e.g. to show a custom message / use custom translation key), you might want to extend the method `BadRequestHandler.handleValidationError()` or `.handleError()`.

See source code: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/1b22bf5376c1fc5a88877aaaf4682f1838347b90/projects/core/src/global-message/http-interceptors/handlers/bad-request/bad-request.handler.ts#L64-L78